# How do I change the background colour of File Explorer in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11

I am trying to change the background colour of file explorer from white to grey.

Tried setting the grey values in the registry for Control Panel → Color → Window to grey (220 220 220) and restarted. But it didn't help. I would like to stay in Windows light mode.

I am attaching a screenshot for reference of the current state. Present color (white):

[image: Present Color (White)]

Comment: Hello, "Control Panel-> Color-> Window to grey(220 220 220)" is not a registry key. Please state what exactly you edited.

Comment: hint: pictures speak a thousand words. This used to be easy (I did it on every box) before vista, but I don't think areo themes let you configure widgets specifically.  perhaps there is a third party app to configure them.

Comment: Simple answer - it's not possible beyond using the dark theme. It hasn't been possible since Win ≤8.1 through Stardock [WindowBlinds](https://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/). Microsoft changed something within the [Windows Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell) between 8.1 and 10, and since then, it hasn't been possible. Explorer background in Win ≥10 isn't controlled by registry keys _(Win ≤8.1 is)_ - some of those registry keys do still have functionality, but unless using a High Contract theme, most do not in Win ≥10.